# Parser Error Reporting deriving the right instances

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I am trying to build an error reporting parser in haskell. Currently I have been looking at a tutorial and this is what I have so far.

```
type Position = (Int, Int)
type Err = (String, Position)
newtype Parser1 a = Parser1 {parse1 :: StateT String (StateT Position (MaybeT
(Either Err))) a} deriving (Monad, MonadState String, Applicative, Functor)

runParser :: Parser1 a -> String -> Either Err (Maybe ((a, String), Position))
runParser p ts = runMaybeT $ runStateT (runStateT (parse1 p) ts) (0, 0)


basicItem = Parser1 $ do
  state <- get
  case state of
    (x:xs) -> do {put xs; return x}
    [] -> empty

item = Parser1 $ do
  c <- basicItem
  pos <- lift get
  lift (put (f pos))
  return c


f :: Char -> Position -> Position
f d (ln, c) = (ln + 1, 0)
f _ (ln, c) = (ln , c + 1)
```

This piece of code does not compile, I think it is to do with my item parser and the fact that I am trying to access the inner state  namely position. I was wondering how in the deriving clause do I make Haskell derive the instances for both states in my parser type, so then I can access the inner state?

Edit 1:

I initially tried declaring basicItem as:

```
basicItem :: (MonadState String m, Alternative m) => m t
basicItem = do
 state <- get
 case state of
   (x:xs) -> do {put xs; return x}
   [] -> empty`
```

However, I kept getting the error:
[image: Error2]

I was wondering why it cannot deduce context of get from MonadState String m,
when in my deriving clause I have MonadState String.

The error for my initial question is here:
[image: Error1]

Comment: Always add the error message.

Comment: `basicItem` is a `Parser1` but you use it in a context (`do { c <- basicItem; ...  }`) which expects a `StateT`. You cannot have two `MonadState` instances for a single type.